# How to highlight some specific days?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to use mui-x-date-pickers to highlight some specific days from a Date array (using new Date), like a green filled circle around the day number. How can I achieve that?

This is my current code:

```
<DatePicker
            label="Date du jour à visualiser"
            openTo="day"
            views={["day", "month", "year"]}
            value={value}
            format="dd.MM.yyyy"
/>
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work. Here is my code:

```
import { isSameDay } from "date-fns";
import { PickersDay, PickersDayProps } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import React from "react";

const highlightedDays: Array<Date> = [new Date("1970-01-01")];

const CustomDay = (props: PickersDayProps<Date>) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
    const matchedStyles = highlightedDays.reduce((a, v) => {
        const date = new Date(props.day);
        return isSameDay(date, v) ? { backgroundColor: "#004b95" } : a;
    }, {});

    return <PickersDay {...props} sx={{ ...matchedStyles }} />;
};

return (<DatePicker
    label="Date du jour à visualiser"
    openTo="day"
    views={["day", "month", "year"]}
    value={value}
    format="dd.MM.yyyy"
    slots={{ day: CustomDay }}
/>);
```

Add some dates in the array, then you're good to go!

Comment: This saved me. Thank you so much :))